# a word/term for having so little knowledge of a subject you can't understand how much work it

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for a word/term for having so little knowledge of a subject you can't understand how much work goes into it.

Comment: Not quite right, but this sounds similar to the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)

Comment: In many contexts ***blissful ignorance*** might be appropriate.

Comment: "Modern-day presidential"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is it called when experts think they only know a small part of a topic and amateurs think they know almost all of a topic?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385505/what-is-it-called-when-experts-think-they-only-know-a-small-part-of-a-topic-and)

Answer (score 1):

This might be too broad, but...

> ### Uninitiated
>
> lacking knowledge of or experience with something : not initiated : inexperienced • *an uninitiated recruit* —[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uninitiated)

Other words that come to mind are *ignorant* and *naïve*.

Answer (score 1):

**dilettante** [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dilettante)

> 1. A person who cultivates an area of interest without real commitment or knowledge.